# Pass NSMutableArray to archivedDataWithRootObject return nil

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an NSMutableArray where i store CLLocation objects from GPS. The problem is when o try to save my array to NSData object in order to insert it in an sqlite database. NSData object has nil value. Until few days ago my code worked fine. I think after an xcode update stoped. A snipset of my code is the following:

```
@interface srTrackMeHome : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate>{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    NSMutableArray *myLocations; 
}
```

on .m file on button click i run the following function:

```
- (IBAction)StartTrackMe:(id)sender {  
        myLocations=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
       [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}


-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{ 
.
.
.
.
[myLocations addObject:newLocation]; 

}
```

and when i have finished collecting my GPS points i try the following(**until this point i can see my array that has data**):

```
NSData *routePointsFromArray = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myLocations];`
```

here is where routePointsFromArray=nil and a few days ago this worked.

Am i missing something? Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you observe the `NSCoding` protocal ?

Comment: Post more relevant code. At the moment, it looks like you never initialize `myLocations`.

Comment: @aircraft i have read that and CLLocations and NSMutablearray conform nscoding protocol. As i said my code worked and still works on devices that have my app but  my code not working after updating my xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue. The above code did save on database my array even if i saw on xcode that has nil value(i really don't know why xcode show nil value). The problem was when i retrieved my data from database. The problem is the way the xcode(i think) runs "if{} else{}" code. When i retrieve data my code should run only "if" part but for some reason the "else" code ran too. i splited my function into two new ones. One manage "if" code and the other one "else" code and everything works fine.

I would really thank you for your time and your answers.

Answer (score 0):

As rmaddy points out, it looks like you never initialize your array, so you "are dropping your location objects on the floor".

You need to add a line to create your array:

```
NSMutableArray *myLocations = [NSMutableArray new];

//Now you can create locations 
[myLocations addObject:newLocation]; //newLocation comes from locationManager
```

In Objective-C you can send a message to a nil object and it just fails silently, so when you didn't create an array object your calls to `addObject` were just being ignored.

Comment: i have updated my initial post with more of my code. My code was ok and running both the app and the code. After an xcode update my code just stop working as it used to on this specific position.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your code, you are adding a object newLocation in myLocations array.

So first, newLocation is your custom model class, right?
Please confirm, Are you implement a NSCodingProtocol on it.

Second,
Please check in method didUpdateLocations, got any response from location manager?

If answer is no then please check your privacy permission of location is added info.plist file.